# Fatal Error : C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ndis.h': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, wdk, ndis

While building my project in VS2022, this ndis error shows up. I have tried googling but unable to find a proper solution. It was mentioned on official doc that *The WDK provides Ndis.h as the main header file for miniport drivers. This file defines the entry points for the miniport driver, the NDIS Library functions, and common data structures.* I have tried re-installing WDK but no success.

Comment: How did you create your project?  If you create a project from the WDK templates, then the includes paths will all be set up correctly.

Comment: Actually this is my internship project, and I had to shift the build environment to VS-2022 from VS-2019. It was successfully compiled in VS-2019 but here I am facing this issue.

Comment: Did you download the latest WDK to go with it?  They're a matched set.  https://www.osr.com/blog/2022/09/21/the-windows-driver-kit-and-visual-studio-2022/

Comment: I am not using the latest WDK. In the article it is mentioned that This new version of the WDK is only support on VS 2022. It cannot be used with VS 2019.  

This implies that New WDK will only work with VS2022 but the Old WDK should work with both VS2019 as well as VS2022 while the . So using the same WDK as it was in VS2019 should not be a problem.

Comment: The WDK and the Visual Studio versions are mated.  There is no guarantee that an older WDK will work with a newer Visual Studio.